# Bash calls and arrays

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm newbie to bash scripting, made this script work as I expected though it's still a first draft:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/site.com/ -type f -name "*.log" | xargs bash -c '
    
    for name; do

    parent=${name%/*}
    parent=${parent##*/}
    destdir=$(dirname $name)
    current_year=$(date +"%Y")

    if [[ "$name" =~ _([0-9]{4})- ]] &&
       [[ "$name" != *"$current_year"* ]]; then
         year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    else continue
    fi


    if [ ! -d "$destdir/$year/$parent" ]; then
         mkdir -p "$destdir/$year/"
    fi
          mv "$name" "$destdir/$year"

done '

find /var/www/site.com/ -type d -name "20*"  | xargs bash -c '

     for dir; do

     tar_name=$(echo $dir | grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}')
     tar cvfj '$tar_name'.tbz $dir 
done '
exit
```

as you can see I'm invoking bash twice inside a bash script . Is that a bad practice ? makes no / little sense ?
Or I'd better off creating an array with the output results of find commands and iterate through it? Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. Sorry for missing indentation

Comment: You'd probably get better answers at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Even without looking inside the inner shell script, some things to note:

Plain `xargs` will fail you if the filenames contain whitespace, quotes or backslash characters. It has its own set of quoting rules incompatible with mostly everything else. (I can't find a reference question right now.)

You're missing the "zeroth" argument to the inline shell script, which will cause the first filename to be skipped.

Also, the syntax highlighting reveals that your second command is broken, the single quotes in `grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}'` close and reopen the quotes surrounding the whole script.

---

Now, the issue with `xargs` is most easily fixed with `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 command...` which are supported in many implementations (GNU, FreeBSD, Busybox).

To fix the issue with the zeroth argument, you need to add a dummy argument (which ends up in `$0`), e.g.

```
... | xargs -0 bash -c '...' sh
```

Or, you could also use `find ... -exec bash -c '...' sh {} +`.

But it's probably better to just avoid launching another shell. In Bash, you could do:

```
find  ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    something with "$file"
done
```

or,

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    something with "$file"
done < <(find ... -print0)
```

The latter works even if you need to set variables within the loop and expect them to be available outside it.

See the relevant parts of [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/170373) (You're not using a command substitution, so not all of it is relevant.)

To put the output of `find` into an array, use

```
mapfile -t -d '' array < <(find ... -print0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have bash ≥4.3, you can use recursive globbing instead of calling `find`. Calling `find` isn't wrong (if you do it right: see below), but it's less convenient when recursive globbing will do. You need to call [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#index-shopt) to enable recursive globbing.

```
shopt -s globstar

for name in /var/www/site.com/**/*.log; do
  …
done

for dir in /var/www/site.com/**/20*/; do
  …
done
```

If you do use `find`, never pipe `find` into `xargs`: they use different syntax to separate file names, so this fails with names containing whitespace or `\'"`. Either use `-exec` to invoke a shell or use `find … -print0 | xargs -0`. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more information.